# Automatic Merging of branches under bugfix/[name-here] to dev in GitHub

Tags: git, github

### Scenario

multiple people are working on multiple branches (one to one relationship) for bug fixes. These branches are designated `bugfix/[name-here]`

There is a system that automatically syncs with a branch called `development`.

I'm looking for a way using GitHub, to have all `bugfix/*` branches automatically merged with the `development` branch on push.

### Considerations

I don't want to have to approve PR's for this as it requires more manual work. I'm looking for a solution that will allow the development branch to be constantly updated and available for testing at any time.

I'm not worried about merge conflicts, since there will not be any cross-over between files between the branches.

I've looked into GitHub actions, but the available actions I've already found seem to be one-to-many merging, where I need many-to-one merging.

New `bugfix/[name-here]` branches will be created new all of the time, I need a method that will use RegEx or something like that when getting a list of the branches so that every time new ones are created, the GitHub action doesn't have to be updated as well.

PR's will need to be created when something is done testing, and so that particular `bugfix/12345` can be merged into master.

I'm under the current assumption that the best case here is for me to write my own GitHub action to achieve what I want.

### Question

Does anyone know of an automation I can just plug and play or is there a better way to go about what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/marketplace/actions/branch-merge. The example does almost exactly what you want: It merges every pushed branch called "release/*" into "master".
Just change

- `release/*` to `bugfix/*`
- `master` to `development`

and you should be set.